# How to make "Theorem 1" and not "Theorem 0.1"

Tags: numbering, theorems

It includes the command `\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[section]` in my code, but theorem 0.1 appears when I do `\begin{teo}`, how to change?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) take a close look at the code you posted, which part do you guess needs to be removed? Hint it is in square brackets. (3) this is not related to latex3, so the tag is wrong.

Comment: You are asking that the theorems are numbered in the form “section.theorem”. If you don't want it, remove `[section]`.

Comment: What if I want it to start with 1.1 and end on some other, type 1.9, but then with 2 with 2.1
separating in chapters I say
How can he not put any number?