# List the theorems according to chapter

Tags: numbering, theorems

I'm writing an article and eating numbering theorems according to the chapter, when I use `\newtheorem` ... elias numar with 1,2,3 ...

How do I number with 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ... as far as I want and from there 
starting to number with 2.1, 2.2 ...

Also, how to write "Definition" in the source of proposals, theorems ... without using the assigned number?

Note: I do not know how to define a chapter yet, is there any way to do a `\begin{chapter}`?

Comment: In as much is your current question different from your other one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397538/how-to-make-theorem-1-and-not-theorem-0-1)? Also there are too much questions in one, and there is only `\chapter`, but not if you use an `article` - like class

Comment: Related (somewhat): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-the-numbering-of-part-chapter-section-to-alphabetical-r